Why can't I reach 2M repeaters, but can easily reach 70cm?
I have a Baofeng 5RM.  There are many repeaters in my area, both 2M and 70cm.  I can reach many 70cm repeaters up to 10-12 miles, but can only reach 1 very close 2M repeater.  I've tried with the longer of two antennas that came with the radio as well as tried with a homemade j pole and homemade vertical dipole.
Any ideas of why I'm basically limited to 70cm?
Thanks.

Did you confirm those 2m repeaters are in operation? Do you have any other 2m setup to test them, or your 70cm repeater buddies who can confirm?

Good point, Ryuji.  I guess I'm not sure they are in operation, but it seems unlikely so many 2M would not be working and so many 70cm would be.  But....I'm not sure.  There is only one 2M repeater that I can reach so at least I know I can transmit and receive on 2M.

Maybe you could ask on the 2m repeater you can access if others are in operation. Band activities vary a lot from area to area. But I only do simplex/direct so someone else may step in to help you on this.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Baofeng/comments/1btf74c/5rm_reception/

You may not be hearing the repeater signal. I'm not sure about 5RM-specific info, but if the receiver design hasn't been improved from previous models, I would expect the 2m receiver to operate poorly due to suppression caused by other VHF communication as well as FM broadcast signals. It may be that you need a bandpass filter (or at least a bandstop for the interfering signals) to clean up the signal before feeding your Baofeng.

Is the correct transmit tone and frequency offset for all those repeaters programmed into your radio ?

There is not enough information in the question.  Describe the antennas you tried.  How high was the j-pole?  Was it inside or outside?  Did you set the tones correctly?  How var away are the repeaters you can't hit?  Did you try moving the antenna within a quarter wave box to find the sweet spot?  Did you listen for a half hour to see if the repeater beacons ID tones?

@user10489 thanks...the jpole was inside in the attic.  The vertical dipole was about 2-3 feet outside a 2nd story window.  The tones were set with data downloaded from repeater book and programmed into radio with chirp -- I assume that worked correctly, but I guess am not sure.  The repeaters I can't hit on 2M but can on 70cm are in the 10-12 mile range.  I did not try moving the antenna to find the sweet spot -- I'm not sure how to do that.  Any advice welcome.   Thx again.

For what Ryuji suggested - what you can do to check is hop on to some websdr that is in your region or the region of the repeater you are trying to activate and check if someone else is able to activate it.
If the repeater is active and other operators are able to activate it you can then as per Mike Waters check the repeaters input and output frequencies and adjust your tone based on that.
